# How to catch AccessViolationException in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#

I have a .Net application I am targetting both .Net framework 4.0 and .Net core 2.0, I have to call some pkcs11 driver using pkcs11interop library due to some driver issue I am getting **AccessViolation Exception** in .net framework 4.0 I was able to handle with attribute `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` on the method but this will not work in .Net core 2.0 how can I handle in .Net core 2.0

as per comment i have added environment variable [image: Environment variable]

but still, unable to catch the exception.[image]

Comment: Setting environment variable "COMPlus_legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy" to "1" should help even in .NET Core. For example with `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("COMPlus_legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy", "1");`, or before starting application. Though doing anything else except logging and exiting process after this exception is not a good idea.

Comment: I tried adding this line in `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("COMPlus_legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy", "1");` program.cs main() but it did not catch the exception.

Comment: Maybe it's too late to do that when application has already started. Try to set this environment variable before starting.

Comment: My application is a self-hosted app which runs on the client side and I am giving it SCD deployment how can I handle this.

Comment: Well just set environment variable with a way appropriate to operating system you run it on, then do `dotnet YourApp.dll` or however you start your application.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Access violations generally come from doing something wrong in unmanaged memory. As with most unexpected exceptions, you shouldn't try to _catch_ it, you should look into what you're doing wrong, and _prevent or fix_ it.

Comment: I'm also, My application is a self-hosted app which runs on the client side , did you solved this issue ?

Comment: May be you can add a C++ wrapper to call the external C++ dll Method and handle the external C++ dll's Exception then PInvoke the C++ Wrapper dll method to avoid  AccessViolationException ?

Answer (score 2):

Please note the following:

> You shouldn't. An access violation is a serious problem: it is an
>   unexpected attempt to write to (or read from) an invalid memory
>   address. As John already clarified, the unmanaged DLL might already
>   have corrupted the process memory before the access violation has been
>   raised. This can have unpredicted effects on any part of the current
>   process.
>
> The safest thing to do is to possibly inform the user and then
>   immediately exit.
>
> Some more details: An access violation is an OS exception (a so-called
>   SEH or *structured exception handling* exception). This is a different
>   kind of exception than the managed CLR exceptions from
>   `System.Exception`. You will rarely see SEH exceptions in purely
>   managed code, but if one occurs, e.g. in unmanaged code, the CLR will
>   deliver it to managed code where you are also able to catch
>   it<sup>1</sup>.
>
> However, catching SEH exceptions is mostly not a good idea. Further
>   details are explained in the article [***Handling Corrupted State
>   Exceptions***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) in MSDN magazine where the following text it taken
>   from:
>
> The CLR has always delivered SEH exceptions to managed code using the same mechanisms as exceptions raised by the program itself. This isn't a problem as long as code doesn't attempt to handle exceptional conditions that it cannot reasonably handle. Most programs cannot safely continue execution after an access violation. Unfortunately, the CLR's exception handling model has always encouraged users to catch these serious errors by allowing programs to catch any exception at the top of the System.Exception hierarchy. But this is rarely the right thing to do.

<sup>1</sup><sub>This was true until .NET 3.5. In .NET 4 the behavior has been changed. If you still want to be able to catch such kind of exceptions you would have to add `legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy=true` to the app.config. Further details in the articled linked above.</sub>

That said, there is a nice question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682489/gracefully-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions-in-net-core) regarding the matter which might suit your case as well.

There is a difference in handling corrupted state exception in .Net Core.

Please refer to this [article](https://techblog.dorogin.com/handling-errors-in-aspnet-core-middleware-e39872496d51) that is concerning error handling in .Net Core, which uses a middleware (which is what I prefer while using extension methods to suit your needs).

Answer (score 1):

If a CSE is possible, you will hard crash. Dark times ahead.

In chronological order...

dotnet/coreclr [Issue #9045](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9045): Strip corrupted state exceptions handling

dotnet/coreclr [PR #10957](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/10957): Do not honor attribute HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions

dotnet/coreclr [Issue #19192](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/19192): Unable to catch in managed code any user exception thrown from native Linux code

SOL currently.
Have to create an unmanaged wrapper of sorts to catch external CSEs.