# Asp.net Core How To Log System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net, access-violation, ilogger

We recently found that our application is throwing `System.AccessViolationException` when utilizing some third party library doing some unmanaged memory access.
I will certainly try to work with the third party to get a fix from them, this post isn't for that though :).

I am hoping for some insights on how I can actually get this exception information into my logs. We're running Asp.net Core 5.
We only found this error by enabling `stdoutLogEnabled` :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis. However, this isn't recommended for production environments.
So my current question is, **how can I actually capture the same log message** `stdoutLogEnabled=true` was able to give us, by using some other logging provider, i.e. `Log4Net`.

I have the following in my appsettings:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
    }
  },
```

And yet, when I run some unsafe code to to simulate the `System.AccessViolationException` I do not see if being logged in any of my `log4net` appenders.

I don't specifically have to get this working for log4net, that is just what we are using today. In general I would like to be able to capture this log using some advanced log provider so that it could potentially log somewhere other than a local file on the server.

Sample log output form the `stdoutLogEnabled` on the server

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Repeat 2 times:
--------------------------------
   at   +.(IntPtr, System.String, Byte[], Int32, IntPtr ByRef, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr ByRef, System.String ByRef)
--------------------------------
   at d.(  , System.String, System.IO.Stream)
   at ThirdPartyClass.Save(System.String, System.IO.Stream)
   at FirstPartyClass.CreateImage()
   at FirstPartyClass.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Edit:
Adding more information. I did read this similar post: [Gracefully handling corrupted state exceptions in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682489/gracefully-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions-in-net-core)
Which does not bode well for my problem. My question does differ though, because I don't care to catch the exceptions, I'm ok with the application crashing. I just want to ensure we can log this information to our log provider of choice when these errors do occur.

Answer (score 0):

İf you didn't try, you can use ILogger interface or Serilog package. You can find helper documentation from the below links.

[Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Serilog](https://serilog.net/)

Comment: Do you happen to know with any certainty whether Serilog will capture these types of exceptions by chance? I will do a POC with Serilog to see for sure, but still curious if you already know the answer before I even put pen to paper :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the unhandled exceptions like this, ensure you are calling `UseExceptionHandler`

In the below link search for "Catches and logs unhandled exceptions"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In the startup class, look for the function

```
public void Configure
```

In that function, ensure you called `UseExceptionHandler` as shown below, as mentioned in the document.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Comment: This does not work, the application crashes without ever running these exceptions, just tested it out. :/