# 'System.AccessViolationException' when switching from mysql/sql client to ODBC client in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mariadb, odbc, access-violation

I have c# code that is taking arguments from an xml file and executing commands from a .sql file passed in to the xml.

I have a case statement for different types of connections.

```
switch (type)
{
    case @"type=mysql":
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        break;

    case @"type=odbc":
        conn = new OdbcConnection(connection);
        break;

}
```

When I run using a mySql or sql client it works fine:

```
MySqlCommand queryCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
queryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but when I switch to an odbc client

```
OdbcCommand queryCmd = new OdbcCommand(query, con);
queryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get

> "Exception thrown: read access violation. stmt was nullptr." And
> "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write
> protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
> corrupt.'"

update: : I tested with a sql server connection and this does execute properly. It fails when using with a MariaDb connection. Also this fails on the execution, not on the connection.

Comment: Sounds like something in your query is making the ODBC driver to crash. Either it's a bug and/or there's something not quite right in the query. People might be able to give you some more insight if you can share the query that makes it crash.

Comment: Check your connection string. In case you need to handle such exception - this is the way https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843347/1704458

Comment: @MartinCostello it crashes on any query. Here is the connectionString "Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};TCPIP=1;Server=127.0.0.1Database=mysql;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;Port=3306"

Comment: update: : I tested with a sql server connection and this does execute properly. It fails when using with a MariaDb connection. Also this fails on the execution, not on the connection.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me:

- check the option to enable multiple statements in the Data Source configuration
- Add "OPTIONS=92344352" to the connection string